# Add python 3.7.1 path on windows 7

Tags: windows-7, python, path, python3

I want to use python from my cmd/bash, I have copied the path and added it the environment variables but it didn't work, python is working fine from python GUI.

I have checked youtube videos there are for older version as the location on the  python folder is currently in the user folder not the windows or C:/ directory.

Answer (score 1):

I have pasted the path into the environment variables as follows:

```
C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37
```

I forgot to add the "python" application to the path as below:

```
C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\python
```

once I have done that it worked fine :)

[image: screenshot]